# Intellij tool window "evaluate expression" can't be opened

Tags: macos, debugging, intellij-idea, config

I'm using intellij 2020.3.2. On one session of my macos system, I can open the evaluate expression window, using the correct shortcut or cliking this :
[image: Evaluate expression icon, centered]. And I can use my debugger with normal behavior.

But I've got another session on the system (same project and seems to be same conditions), where it is impossible to open this tool window, whatever I test. I can debug, set a break point and see the value by "quick evaluate", but the evaluate expression window cannot be opened.

At this point I do not give more infos on the project cause I don't think it makes a diff...

I tried in a first place with another empty project, I have the same behavior, so it is possible that it's a macos issue, I don't know.
I also tried to reinstall the IDE on this second session, but it does the same.

After I've done some unsuccessful search, I come here and directly ask if you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is **Show toolbar** option in the [Debug tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-tool-window.html):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I didn't express the problem correctly. I click on the right icon, but nothing happens... so I already see this toolbar

Answer (score 0):

After an update, problem is solved.